# Display CDATA with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, cdata

I'm working with a bowling website and a software program written for management of our bowling league scores. The software also allows us to write an article on the last bowling league day. Now I'm copying the article into HTML module on the website but since it's also implemented in the same XML output file as the scores I'd like to take it out as well with XSLT. I only don't know what are the commands for this... So I have no XSLT file I'm working with. If I look it up here or on google , there seem to be tons of ways to do it but every time there's a bunch of other code as well and I'm still a beginner... 
Can anybody help me?

```
<Infos>
    <Info>
        <Title><![CDATA[THIS IS THE TITLE OF THE ARTICLE]]></Title>
        <Text><![CDATA[THIS THE ARTICLE]]></Text>
    </Info>
</Infos>
```

Comment: XSLT does not see CDATA sections anyway, but the real problem with your question is: I have no idea what you are asking. Please explain more clearly what your problem is, and show the expected output (HTML, I guess).

Comment: The CDATA piece contains text, I want it to display after applying XSLT and determine the text outcome (bold, Italic and underlined) with XSLT

Comment: If you do not know what you would like to transform your input to, we cannot help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

> The CDATA piece contains text, I want it to display after applying
>   XSLT and determine the text outcome (bold, Italic and underlined) with
>   XSLT

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Infos">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Info"/>
        </body>
    </html>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="Title" /></h2>
    <i><xsl:value-of select="Text" /></i>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will produce the following **result**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>THIS IS THE TITLE OF THE ARTICLE</h2>
      <i>THIS THE ARTICLE</i>
   </body>
</html>
```

rendered as:

[image]